# Python try connecting to multiple mysqldb hosts

Tags: python, mysql, multiple-databases

Wondering if there is a way to use a python script to attempt a connection to a group mysql database hosts?  Ideally there would be X number of hosts and it would try connecting to each, then fail if no connection could be made.  I do not believe MySQLdb.connect is capable of handling multiple hosts, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: So why cannot you just do MySQLdb.connect in a loop, trying different host each iteration?

Comment: Perhaps adding your 'connect' statements in a map/dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqldb.connect` is perfectly ok with connecting to multiple hosts:

```py
try:
    conn1 = mysqldb.connect(...)
    conn2 = mysqldb.connect(...)
    ...
except:  # add specific exception here
    ...  # support failure when connecting
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about try/except (new to python).